# Delete firebase analytics events

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is there any way or some kind of "hack" to immediately delete events logged in to my firebase or google analytics project? I heard that it is possible to create some kind of cloud function which is eligible to delete events, but I was unable to find any clue how to do it after several hours of googling.

Comment: I have posted the answer,Hope that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics User Deletion API allows to process deletions of data associated with a given user identifier [Requesting data deletions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3). There is a drop down menu on the top right corner of the events dashboard. You have a ton of options and you can even set a custom time frame.

As far as doing this from Functions, it's a microservice; if there is an API to call and you have credentials, you can do it from Functions.

Cloud Functions supports Google Analytics [AnalyticsEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events#trigger_a_function). With Cloud Functions, you can access conversion events you have logged and trigger functions based on those events. This event is triggered whenever user activity generates a conversion event. you could write a function that triggers when the event is generated, indicating that event has occurred.

[Google Analytics for Firebase triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/google-analytics-firebase) the log event. This is a powerful event type, since any action that a user takes in your app can be logged and in turn trigger a function.

For example, you could write a function that triggers when the `in_app_purchase event` is generated, indicating that an in-app purchase has occurred. You must specify the Analytics event that you want to trigger your function using the `functions.analytics.event()` method, and handle the event within the `onLog()` event handler:

```
exports.sendCouponOnPurchase = functions.analytics.event('in_app_purchase').onLog((event) => {
  // Your code to handle delete
});
```